# Como usar otra cuenta de github en Windows

Tags: git, github, git-push

tengo el problema de que ya tengo mi cuenta de github principal logeada en la terminal.
Ahora quiero usar una cuenta secundaria que acabo de crear de github pero no puedo hacerle push a los repositorios porque hace los push con las credenciales de mi cuenta principal.
Cómo borro las credenciales de mi cuenta principal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Selecciona Panel de control
2. Cuentas de usuario
3. Administrar credenciales

Buscas las credenciales de git y cambia tu usuario y contraseña

Answer (score 2):

Via consola accedes al repositorio y usas los siguientes comandos:

```
git config user.name "Max Jimenez"
git config user.email "max.jimenez@email.com"
```

Con esto asignas estos valores **solamente** al repositorio en el que estás ubicado. Si lo que deseas es cambiar los datos de manera global, debes usar la opcion `--global` así:

```
git config --global user.name "Max Jimenez"
git config --global user.email "max.jimenez@email.com"
```

---

Ahora, para cambiar la configuracion del remoto puedes hacer esto: Primero lista el remoto que tienes configurado, cuya salida es algo similar a:

```
$ git remote -vv
origin  https://username@github.com/owner/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://username@github.com/owner/repo.git (push)
```

Ahora puedes usar para eliminar el usuario:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/owner/repo.git
```

O este para cambiar a otro usuario

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://nuevousuario@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

Espero te sirva esta información

Comment: Aquí estás hablando de las credenciales de git,  y la pregunta es sobre las credenciales de github.

Comment: Tienes razón. Puedes revisar tu configuración de remotos y modificar la URL para que incluya el nombre de usuario que deseas usar o eliminar el nombre de usuario para que te lo pida cada vez que haces un push

Comment: Donde encuentro esa config compañero? Esa me suena a que es justo la que necesito. Edita la respuesta por favor

Comment: @MaxJimenez, He editado la respuesta añadiendo esto último.